# How do I create a countdown timer that persists when I browse to other pages of my app?

Tags: meteor

I'm making a simple app where I start a countdown timer, and when the timer expires it shows a template. On that template, I answer a series of questions, then then submit the answers to the database.

At the moment, my countdown timer just written in JavaScript like this:

```
    Template.start.events({
    'click .startTimer': function() {

        $("#timer").text();

        (function() {
            var wait = 2;
            var countSpan = $('#timer span');

            function countdown() {

                wait -= 1;

                if (wait > 0) {
                    countSpan.text(wait);
                    setTimeout(countdown, 1000);
                    $('.startTimer').prop("disabled", true);
                    Session.set('done', false);

                } else {
                    Session.set('done', true);
                    $('.startTimer').prop("disabled", false);
                    countSpan.text("Complete checkup then keep working!");

                }
            }
            setTimeout(countdown, 1000);

        }());
    }
});
```

**The problem is that when I navigate away from the page that's printing out the countdown, it doesn't persist.**

How do I make a countdown timer within my app that will keep going while I navigate to other pages within the app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using meteorhacks:async to accomplish this. Here's the code:

```
    function delayedMessge(callback) {
        Meteor.setTimeout(function() {
            callback(null, true)
        }, 1000)
    }

    var wrappedDelayedMessage = Async.wrap(delayedMessge);

    Meteor.methods({
        'abc': function() {
            var response = wrappedDelayedMessage();
            return response;
        }
    });

    Template.start.events({

    'click .start': function() {

        Meteor.call('abc', function(error, response){
            var timeup = response
            //I'm setting this session to true, then in a helper
            //that isn't shown here, I'm getting the Session and
            //which displays the template
            Session.set('done', timeup)
        });
      }
    })
```

azium's answer led me in the right direction but wasn't quite right. I did end up running a setTimeout within a method but there was a problem. The callback associated with the Meteor.call is executed right away, but the setTimeout within the mehod hasn't finished yet. With the meteorhacks:async package, the Meteor.call callback function waits until the setTimeout fires.

Answer (score 0):

What about this pseudo idea:

1. Once you navigate away form the page (tab blur of some sorts), save
   variable in the Session with current timestamp
   `Session.set("leavingAt", new Date())`
2. Once you return to the page (equivalent tab focus), save new variable with current timestamp
   `Session.set("returningAt", new Date())`
3. Add/substract difference between both (depending on how you implement) and update your countdown timer

Answer (score 0):

You could start the timer on the server using a Meteor method.

```
// call method from template
Meteor.call('startTimer', function() {
  // handle timer finished logic
});

//server
Meteor.methods({
  startTimer: function() {
    Meteor.setTimeout(function() {
      //do something
      return;
    }, ms)
  }
});
```

I think your callback will still be triggered even if you're on a different template, but I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: Your answer led me in the right direction. Doing a setTimeout on the server is the best way to do this. However, with Meteor.call, the callback function executes before the setTimeout is finished.